# Find the Angles 1 to 3 so that the Reactional Forces Become Minimal

Tags: mechanical-engineering, kinematics, geometry, forces

My question regards the following system:
[image]

- This system is supposed to be located in a plane, so it is 2-dimensional.
- It consists of three rods, which are connected at the ends. Meeting in the hinges $II$ and $III$.
- The hinges $I$ and $IV$ are fixed in position. Leaving for only one degree of freedom in the system.
- Beyond this, the rods 1 and 2 and also the rods 2 and 3 are connected with torsion springs resulting in rotational forces once the relative angle between them deviates from 90°.

To summarize:

- The lengths $l_1$, $l_2$, $l_3$ and $l_4$ are given. ($l_4$ being the length from point $I$ to point $IV$)
- The constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ for the torsion springs are given.

I am currently stumped trying to find the angles $\varphi$ 1 to 3, where the reactional forces of the system become minimal.

These are the mathematical equations I was able do derive so far:

$$0=l_1sin(\varphi_1)+l_2sin(\varphi_2)+l_3sin(\varphi_3)$$

$$l_4=l_1cos(\varphi_1)+l_2cos(\varphi_2)+l_3cos(\varphi_3)$$

$$\frac{c_1(\Delta\varphi_{12}-\frac{\pi}{2})}{l_1sin(\varphi_1)}=\frac{c_2(\Delta\varphi_{23}+\frac{\pi}{2})}{l_3sin(\varphi_3)}$$

$$\Delta\varphi_{12}=\varphi_2-\varphi_1$$

$$\Delta\varphi_{23}=\varphi_3-\varphi_2$$

Comment: Your diagram is misleading, that configuration as drawn would need an external force or torque applied.

Comment: @GregLocock I changed it, I hope it is more clear now.